# Interactions (stats) in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

I was wondering if there was a function which can give me all interactions given an input of vectors.

for example:

If I had three vectors a,b,c. Their values are:

```
a = [1,9,3]
b = [4,3,2]
c = [6,5,7]
```

then I can get back a matrix with:

```
[a.*b, a.*c, b.*c ]
```

Comment: What do you mean by `*c`?

Comment: @PseudoAj It's MATLAB syntax. `b.*c` means to element-wise multiply the vectors `b` and `c` together to generate a new vector for example.

Answer (score 1):

The needed computation doesn't have an inbuilt function but you can always write your own:

```
%% Define the vectors
a = [1,9,3];
b = [4,3,2];
c = [6,5,7];

%% test function
pairWiseAppend(a,b,c)

%% Define the function
function customVector = pairWiseAppend(a,b,c)
    %multiply and generate new vectors
    vec1 = a.*b;
    vec2 = a.*c;
    vec3 = b.*c;
    %append the vectors
    customVector = [vec1,vec2,vec3];
end
```

Output:

```
>> stckOvrflow1

ans =

     4    27     6     6    45    21    24    15    14
```

Further, you can always modify the function to suit your needs, for example, this will return a two-dimensional array:

```
%% Define the vectors
a = [1,9,3];
b = [4,3,2];
c = [6,5,7];

%% test function
customArray = pairWiseAppend(a,b,c)

%% Some extra actions on returned array


%% Define the function
function customArray = pairWiseAppend(a,b,c)
    %multiply and generate new vectors
    vec1 = a.*b;
    vec2 = a.*c;
    vec3 = b.*c;
    %append the vectors
    customArray = [vec1;vec2;vec3];
end
```

Output:

```
>> stckOvrflow1

customArray =

     4    27     6
     6    45    21
    24    15    14
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, but I need it to be variable for the amount of IV (independent variables) because its easy to do for 3 IV, but what about for 6?